# more than one source of data to process with bc

Tags: linux, bash, bc

I have this file that contains number in a column:

```
[root@server1]# cat numbers.txt
30
25
15
```

I need to add them together so I do this:

```
[root@autonoc cattests]# cat numbers.txt |  paste -s -d+ | bc
70
```

But after I add them together I need to divide them by 60,something like this:

```
[root@server1]# cat numbers.txt |  paste -s -d+ | "new command" | bc
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bc -l <<< '('$(paste -s -d+ numbers.txt)')/60'
```

Comment: Might put double quotes around the command substitution. Not all versions of bash handle unquoted expansions in herestrings well.

Comment: `bc -l <<< "( $(paste -s -d+ numbers.txt) )/60"`

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{s+=$1} END{print s/60}' numbers.txt
1.16667
```

#### How it works

- `s+=$1`

  The number on each lien of `numbers.txt` is added to variable `s`.
- `END{print s/60}`

  After we have finished reading the file, we print the value of `s` divided by 60.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v div=60 '{tot+=$0}END{print tot/div}' numbers.txt
```

Using the `-v div=60` can be extended further to accept any user input, like

```
read -p "Enter the div value: " div
awk -v div="$div" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dc

```
dc -f numbers.txt -e '++3k60/[result = ]np'
```